# in angularjs 2, Issue with updating DOM content

Tags: angularjs, angular

in angularjs 2 i want to implement Print functionality.

Steps for implementing this are:-
1. on button click i want to fetch data from server.
2. on success, store that data in an array property inside Component class (By this DOM updated automatically) and call my custom print function which fetch DOM Content and place it in another window and calls print to open print dialog box.

Problem:
when i update property, then DOM is not updated automatically right when i assign the new value. it will update automatically after some time. in that time if my print function got executed then i got the old DOM content.

Code: on button click, i fetched data from server and passed that data to setContent method.

```
//set properties of component
setContent(data: any, columns: any): void {
this.customCollection = data;
this.columnsToPrint = columns;

//by setting above 2 properties i was assuming that DOM content is updated by this. Now i call function to print the content
this.printContent();
}

printContent(): void {
var printContents = document.getElementById("divPrintContent").innerHTML;
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1200,height=800');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="/app/shared/PRINT/print.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();       
return;
}
```

Now when new window open (for print) it does not show the updated data but on inspecting DOM of parent window (by F12) i found the content is updated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post your code. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://angular.io

Comment: What part of the "DOM is not updated automatically"? This statement seems related to Angular bindings but I can't see bindings in the code in your question.